# Validating number of months between two dates if created date is before or after the 15th?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database with a user entry form to create an order with an effective date. The effective date is the 1st of the next month (current month +1) if the creation date is before the 15th, or the 1st of the following month (current month +2) if the creation date is the 15th or later.

I would like the VBA code to determine if the created date is before or after the 15th, run a comparison to make sure the effective date is either 1 or 2 months ahead as appropriate, and show an exception message if the effective date input is not valid.

My code worked until last week, when we had an unexpected outage and the database shut down. Now it throws the exception message regardless of the effective date input:

```vb
Private Sub EffDue_AfterUpdate()

    If Format(Me.PCCreated, "DD") < 15 Then
    
        Dim CurrentDate As Date
        Dim IntervalType As String
        Dim Number As Integer
        Dim EffDate As Date
        IntervalType = "m"
        Number = 1
        CurrentDate = Me.PCCreated

        EffDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, CurrentDate)
    
    ElseIf Format(EffDate, "MM") < Format(Me.EffDue, "MM") Then
        Me.Text99 = "Please review the effective due date"
    ElseIf Format(EffDate, "MM") > Format(Me.EffDue, "MM") Then
        Me.Text99 = "Please review the effective due date"
    ElseIf Format(EffDate, "MM") = Format(Me.EffDue, "MM") Then
        Me.Text99 = ""
    End If
    
    If Format(Me.PCCreated, "DD") >= 15 Then
    
        IntervalType = "m"
        Number = 2
        CurrentDate = Me.PCCreated

        DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, CurrentDate) = EffDate
    
    ElseIf Format(EffDate, "MM") < Format(Me.EffDue, "MM") Then
        Me.Text99 = "Please review the effective due date"
    ElseIf Format(EffDate, "MM") > Format(Me.EffDue, "MM") Then
        Me.Text99 = "Please review the effective due date"
    ElseIf Format(EffDate, "MM") = Format(Me.EffDue, "MM") Then
        Me.Text99 = ""
    End If
    
    If Format(Me.EffDue, "DD") > 1 Then
        Me.Text99 = "The effective due date should be the 1st"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

My latest revision identifies if the created date is before or after the 15th, but it doesn't correctly calculate the effective date:

```vb
Private Sub EffDue_AfterUpdate()
    Dim CurrentDay As Integer
    Dim EffDate As Date
    Dim CurrentMonth As Integer
    Dim EffMonth As Integer
    
    CurrentDay = DatePart("d", Me.PCCreated)
    CurrentMonth = DatePart("m", Me.PCCreated)
        
    If CurrentDay >= 15 Then

        EffDate = DateAdd("M", 2, Me.PCCreated)
        EffMonth = DatePart("m", EffDate)
     
    ElseIf CurrentMonth > EffMonth Then
        Me.Text95 = "The effective due date should be " & MonthName(EffMonth) & " 1st"
    ElseIf CurrentMonth < EffMonth Then
        Me.Text95 = "The effective due date should be " & MonthName(EffMonth) & " 1st"
    ElseIf CurrentMonth = EffMonth Then
        Me.Text95 = ""
    End If
    
    If CurrentDay < 15 Then
    
        EffDate = DateAdd("M", 1, Me.PCCreated)
        EffMonth = DatePart("m", EffDate)
    
    ElseIf CurrentMonth > EffMonth Then
        Me.Text95 = "The effective due date should be " & MonthName(EffMonth) & " 1st"
    ElseIf CurrentMonth < EffMonth Then
        Me.Text95 = "The effective due date should be " & MonthName(EffMonth) & " 1st"
    ElseIf CurrentMonth = EffMonth Then
        Me.Text95 = ""
    End If
    
    If Day(Me.EffDue) > 1 Then
        Me.Text95 = "The effective due date should be the 1st"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not have the form populate the Effective date by applying the business rule to the create date, instead of validating a user-supplied effective date?

Comment: Sometimes weirdness is due to corruption. Try decompiling and recompiling db to see if that fixes. If not, might have to rebuild something, maybe just the form, maybe create new file and import objects. Google the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```vb
    Dim CreateDate As Date, EffCalc As Date
    Dim mAdd As Long, msg As String
    
    CreateDate = Me.PCCreated
    mAdd = IIf(Day(CreateDate) <= 15, 1, 2) 'months to add
    
    EffCalc = DateAdd("m", mAdd, CreateDate)               'add month(s)
    EffCalc = DateSerial(Year(EffCalc), Month(EffCalc), 1) '1st of that month
    
    If EffCalc <> Me.EffDue Then
        msg = "Effective date should be " & Format(EffCalc, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End If
    Me.Text99 = msg
```